# Modification of this regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How can I improve the following regex to effectively search for C, CLK, and CE ports and specific printing associated on that ports?

Right now code below detects C, CLK and CE but are all labeled as C port, which is not intended.

Sample code below:

```
import re
test_array = ['jclk','jce','ja','jb','jc','jd','je']

for thisEntry in test_array:
    if re.match(r'jc', thisEntry):
        print("this is C port")
    elif re.match(r'jce', thisEntry):
        print("this is CE port")
    elif re.match(r'jclk', thisEntry):
        print("this is CLK port")
    else:
        print("dont care")
```

Result:

```
this is C port      #for 'jclk', incorrect
this is C port      #for 'jce', incorrect
dont care           #for 'ja', correct
dont care           #for 'jb', correct
this is C port      #for 'jc', correct
dont care           #for 'jd', correct
dont care           #for 'je', correct
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use anchors. btw I din't understand why are you using regex here. Can you not use `thisEntry == 'jc'` condition?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. The reason why I am not using `thisEntry == 'jc'` is that on real application I am accessing a dictionary from a class, in which the value is not just a simple 'j*' arguments.

Comment: ok then use word boundary or anchors as: `re.match(r'\bjc\b', thisEntry):`

Comment: I tried that and it works now, for I was able to differentiate the C, CE and CLK ports. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment to an answer.

You are running into this problem because `jc` is part of many input strings you have.

You need to use anchors or word boundary like this to avoid matching extra text:

```
import re
test_array = ['jclk','jce','ja','jb','jc','jd','je']

for thisEntry in test_array:
    if re.match(r'\bjc\b', thisEntry):
        print("this is C port")
    elif re.match(r'\bjce\b', thisEntry):
        print("this is CE port")
    elif re.match(r'\bjclk\b', thisEntry):
        print("this is CLK port")
    else:
        print("dont care")
```